# Terraform AWS StackSet deployment based on AWS account Tags

Tags: terraform, aws-cloudformation, terraform-provider-aws, aws-organizations

I'm managing AWS organization from Terraform and also manage several CloudFormation StackSets from Terraform. I'm passing below variables from root module to create the accounts, so that my child module have created the AWS accounts.

```html
accounts = {
  "dev" = {
    "name"  = "dev"
    "email" = "dev@myemail.com"
    "tags" = {
      "Owner"       = "DevOps"
      "Env" = "test"
    }
  },
  "stg" = {
    "name"  = "stg"
    "email" = "dev@myemail.com"
    "tags" = {
      "Owner"       = "DevOps"
      "Env" = "test"
    }
  }
  "prod" = {
    "name"  = "prod"
    "email" = "DevOps"
    "tags" = {
      "Owner"       = "DevOps"
      "Env" = "Prod"

    }
  },
  ....
```

As I mentioned above, I already managing several StackSets from this same code base. But those StackSets are really common across all accounts and I have no problem with them. But I want to deploy another StackSet, which the stacks should be created only in Accounts, those Tag `Env = test` but not others. That way I can manage different stacks across accounts based on their tags. Can anyone pass me a clue to how to filter accounts, based on Tags?.

I know this is little complicated to explain. But I will try to provide information as much as possible.

**Update:**

I managed to get below local variables from module outputs

```html
locals {
  account_ids   = module.organization.organization_accounts.*.id
  account_types = module.accounts.tags_all.*.Env
  test_account_ids = ??
}

    Changes to Outputs:
      + account_id   = [
          + "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
          + "yyyyyyyyyyyy",
          + "zzzzzzzzzzzz",
          ...
        ]
      + account_type = [
          + "test",
          + "test",
          + "prod",
          ...
        ]
```

Now how can loop `account_id` and `account_type` and create another local variable to filter account_ids (test_account_ids), which the tag `Env = test`? (using the list index). So I can pass that list of accounts to the child module.

Comment: By account you mean the account name that you defined or an AWS account ID?

Comment: @MarkoE I meant AWS Account ID. My CloudFormation Stackset Terraform module looks for the account IDs.

Comment: @MarkoE could you please check my updated content?.

Comment: And is there a mapping between what the test account is and it's ID?

Comment: @MarkoE there is no mapping in the code level. I taken it from the TF state. That's what you see in my latest update. What I was thinking is to loop through the index of of both `account_ids` and `account_types` local variables and build `test_account_ids` variable (Which include accounts id's which has `Env=test`). Because I believe there is 1 to 1 relation between this indexes, as they comes from the state.  (But I'm not sure how to do this from the code level)